# Installing dual boot operating system

Tags: operating-systems

I want to install Microsoft windows server 2012 within windows 7 and then my pc will be dual boot operating system. What the process of it?

Comment: Are you talking about a VM or dual boot?  With dual boot, you don't install one inside the other.  They are totally separate and you choose which you want to run.  With a VM, you run one inside the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back in the days when I had my desktop PC. I used to partition my hard disk into multiple drives and install multiple windows OS in those separate drives. Like Windiows XP on C drive and Windows 7 on D drive. The OS selection screen would come up after your BIOS finished loading. I guess this would applies even today.

Partition your hard disk using Adminstrative tools>Computer Management>Disk Management under Storage option.

Dont forget to choose separate drives when you install Operating systems.

Cheers.

Comment: I am going to install server 2012 from USB flash drive(8gb), but I can't boot into it from bios.  There is many options to boot first device but nothing works. The options are: 1) HARD DISK 2) CDROM 3) USB FDD 4)USB ZIP 5)USB CDROM 6)USB HDD

Comment: Do you know if the files on the flash drive allows you to boot into it? There are a couple of programs which helps you to turn your flash drive and an ISO image into a bootable one.for example https://rufus.akeo.ie/

Comment: I have done the flash drive  bootable and load iso file into it using ISOtoUSB software.